# Counting occurences of a Letter in an infinite String

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, character

I have the following String called `s="abcac"` that is repeated infinitely many times. This means that `s` will look like: `s="abcacabcacabcacabcacabcac...."` and `n` represents the substring of `s`.

For example, if `s="monday"` and `n="10"`, the substring that we consider will be `finalString="mondaymond"`, since the infinite string will be `"mondaymondaymondaymonday..."` and the first 10 characters of `s` are `"mondaymond"`

I am trying to count the occurrences of the letter "a" in `finalString`. This code is working properly, however when n>1000000 the program won't work.

In addition, if I change `n` from `int` to `long`, the for loop won't work in this case.

What would be the solution to this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

            String s="abcac";
            int aCount=0;
            int n=1000;
            int j=0;


            char[] sCharArray=s.toCharArray();

            char[] finalString = new char[n];

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

                if(j==s.length())
                    j=0;

                finalString[i]=sCharArray[j];
                j++;


            }


            for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
                if(finalString[i]=='a')
                    aCount++;
            }


    System.out.println(aCount);

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest finding how many times the base string is repeated, and the computing the occurrences of the letter using this information, plus the number of occurrences of the extra substring at the very end.  For example:

```
String s = "monday";
int n = 10;
String chr = "a";

int baseNum = s.length() - s.replace(chr, "").length();
int baseCnt = (n / s.length()) * baseNum;
int index = n % s.length();
String left = s.substring(0, index);
int finalCnt = left.length() - left.replace(chr, "").length();
int totalCnt = baseCnt + finalCnt;

System.out.println("There were " + totalCnt + " letter " + chr + ".");
```

The basic idea here is efficiency.  We don't actually need to create and work with a string of arbitrary length, because we know that it just repeats the same substring.  Instead, we can just count occurrences in the substring, and project the total number by how many times that substring repeats.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is the pure "mathematical" algorithm which I was looking for! very efficient with no loops or duplicated arrays.

Comment: Actually this solution does not cover the case when type of `n` is changed to `long` as mentioned by @yasserkabbout in his question.

Comment: @ETO I have modified the algorithm to long. The mathematical approach is better.. what do you think?

Comment: @ETO You're right, but `String#length()` returns an integer, not a long, so theoretically speaking the infinite string can't have a length which doesn't fit into an integer.  Anyway, this question was more about the algorithm than the point you have brought up.

Comment: @yasserkabbout Well, all three solutions have the same mathematical approach under the hood. Theoretically the length of `s` can be a very big number (up to MAX_INT). What I suggest is to avoid using `.substring` and `.replace` in this particular case as their aggregated complexity is much more than just O(n) in my case.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed in other answers, you don't need to build your final string.

Here's my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "abcacas";
    long n = 1000000;

    long count = getCount(s, n, 'a');
    System.out.println(count);
}

private long getCount(String str, long n, char c) {
    int length = str.length();

    long repeats = n / length;
    long reminder = n % length;

    long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
            count += repeats;
            if (i < reminder) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I checked the code on my IDE however it didn't work as the n type was integer. However, I see that it is working now after you've changed the variable type to long.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct your final string. You just have to count occurances of 'a' (or whatever you want) in the `s` string, and count, how many times this `s` repeats. And after all, count the occurances of 'a' in the reminder.

```
long countInS = // count all occurances of 'a'
long repeats = n / s.length;
long reminder = n % s.length;
String sReminder = s.substring(reminder);
long countInReminder = // count all occurances of 'a' in sReminder 
long count = repeats * countInS + countInReminder;
```

no need to waste your RAM

Answer (score 0):

We could optimise further by calculating the remainder before counting occurences and use it like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=ip.next();
    int n=ip.nextInt();
    int res=0;
    int c=0,len=s.length(),cnt=0;
    for(;cnt<len;cnt++){
    if(s.charAt(cnt)=='a')
    c++;
    if(n%len!=0&&cnt==(n%len)-1)
    res=c;
    }
    int mul=n/len;
    System.out.println((mul*c)+res);
    }
}
```